# Why does my deployed eclipse plugin throws NoClassDefFoundError exception?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, noclassdeffounderror

I'm asking and answering this question to save me from going down this rat hole again in the future.

I'm building a cross platform eclipse IDE based software development environment with about 40 plugins.  When I installed the latest nightly build and did some testing on my Linux test system the application started throwing the dreaded java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when I did a certain action. This was not happening on my Windows installation.  It did not happen in my development environments on Linux or Windows.  This action and the code behind it is new and so not yet covered in our automated test suite.

The plugin throwing the exception was trying to access a static class method in another plugin, but failing to find the class.  Things I tried:

1. First thought: static initializer fails for some reason!  Nope.  I can see other plugins access this static class and methods prior to the failure (by attaching my debugger to the installed instance of my product and stepping through the code).
2. The fact that it works from other plugins eliminate the other usual reason for failure, not properly exporting the package.  It was exported correctly.
3. I poured over my plugin dependency list, comparing them to plugins that were able to access the offending class, but with no success. All dependencies were accounted for.
4. I did a deep dive into my MANFEST.MF.  I switched from using "Required-Bundle" to "Import-Package" in the MANIFEST.MF. That created new problems for me so I reverted that change.  Everything looked good.
5. My build.properties looked good.  Not too much in there to go wrong.  It was consistent with my MANFIEST.MF where it counts.
6. I deconstructed my plugin on the installed instance to be sure that the class was indeed present. It was.

Everything was configured correctly.  Everything!

I poured over many related SO questions and blog posts but none of them offered a solution that worked or any additional insight into the problem.

The next step was to start iterating over my nightly builds to find the build where the problem first showed up.  Once I identify that build, I'd be able to iterate over all the commits from the day before, doing full builds, then installs to find the commit that broke it.

I started 10 days prior and installed every nightly build. All the way up to the build that failed in my test environment.  Every single one of them worked.  Why?.  See my answer below (or submit you own).

Answer (score 1):

When testing a new eclipse IDE build make sure you start with a fresh new non-existent workspace directory and use the "-clean" command line parameter to flush any caches that survive from a previous installation.

The failure was happening because I (1) failed to delete my previous workspace directory before starting the application; and (2) did not use the "-clean" command line parameter to delete related cached information; and (3), even "-clean" may not be enough, I also removed the entire application directory (which, in turn, removed the 'configuration' directory and all cached data within that may not have been "cleaned" by the "-clean" command line argument).

I had been refactoring a few class names to have more meaningful names. When I ran the product with an existing environment the product was using cached data,  getting the old name of a class that had been renamed, and failing to resolve it.  (You might think that seeing the old name was a good clue, but, unfortunately, one of the first things I tried was undoing the class name refactoring, thus restoring the previous name.  So the error reported the correct name, but, I suspect, there is a signature of sorts that did not resolve.)

Of course it is a best practice to always start with a new workspace when testing.  I've been doing Eclipse IDE development for years and I know this well.  But yesterday I forgot (not helped by the fact that my Windows installation did not suffer the same error for whatever reason).  You will forget on occasion...and it will bite you.